# Is there a way to create 'truly' custom component in MUI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I know that I can customize standard MUI components like Button, but can I create my own MyCustomButton, that will have `'muiName' = 'MyCustomButton'` and that could be customized via theme configurations:

```
createTheme({
  components: { 
    MyCustomButton: {
      styleOverrides: { 
        root: {...}, 
        MyCustomButtonSubComponent: {...}
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. Let say you want to create a fully customized button with MUI button's behavior.

You can use `ButtonUnstyled` or the `useButton` hook.

https://mui.com/components/buttons/#unstyled